# How can I specify uniqueness on multiple field in mongo, NOT combined?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have the following JSON schema in MongoDB:

```
{"email": "example@gmail.com", "second_email": "example222@gmil.com"}
```

How can I enforce that both fields will be unique separately AND also be unique between them.

i.e the following document will not be valid:

```
{"email":"anotherone@gmail.com", "second_email":"example@gmail.com"}
```

Because `example@gmail.com` is already exists in another document in the other field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head, no database can do this (use another column/field as source data for uniqueness constraint). You will need to do some reshaping of data to achieve this. The easiest way is a unique constraint on an array field.

```
> db.foo.createIndex({ emails: 1 }, { unique: true } )

> db.foo.insert({ emails: ['example@gmail.com', 'example222@gmail.com'] })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.foo.insert({ emails: ['anotherone@gmail.com', 'example@gmail.com'] })
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.foo.$emails_1 dup key: { : \"example@gmail.com\" }"
    }
})
```

Now, depending on your app logic, this emails array can even replace your original two fields. Or not. Up to you. If not, you'll need insert both the original fields **and** duplicate them in this array for the uniqueness check.

Comment: Btw you should be using `createIndex` instead of  `ensureIndex`

Comment: @user3100115: oh, new api? In which version was it introduced? :)

Comment: Well `ensureIndex` is deprecated in 3.0.

Comment: I just realized that even the unique index on the array field will not help in this case. Try `db.foo.insert({ emails: ['foo@gmail.com', 'foo@gmail.com'] })`

Comment: @user3100115: indeed. But this is, perhaps, impossible situation in his app. Or, at least, easily preventable. For example, if this is a follower-followed relationship, one can be certain that app logic will prevent a user from following himself. :) (not show a button or whatever)

Comment: @user3100115: maybe not. But guarding from this situation is trivial - one little `if` in the app and no additional queries. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on each field to enforce uniqueness for the fields.

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { "unique": true } )
db.collection.createIndex( { "second_email": 1 }, { "unique": true } )
```

That being said, MongoDB doesn't not provides a way to enforce uniqueness for two fields  in the same documents. This is something you will need to do in your application using an *if/else* statement.

Another option as shown in this  [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37991923/3100115) is to use an *indexed* array field if you do not want to call the [`createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) method multiple times. But you still need to  use logical condition processing if you don't want duplicate value in the array.

Comment: With indexed array, you don't need the individual field indexes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "mails.email": 1, "mails.second_email": 1 }, { unique: true } )

db.collection.insert( { _id: 3, mails: [ { email: "example@gmail.com", second_email: "example222@gmil.com" } ] } )
```

now you created a "email - second email" pair combination for enforce uniqueness this two field.

Also, if you use bulk option you can set ordered as false to continue with remaining inserts when one fails.. insertMany({},{ordered: false})